# Post to a mongoose schema with array of objects

Tags: mongodb, post, postman, mongoose-schema

I want to post some data to my mongo database.

However the structure of the schema confuses me about the implementation.

This is the schema:

```
var GraphSchema = new Schema({
nodes: [{id: String}],
links: [{source:String, target: String}]
});
```

This is what I've tried so far but it doesn't seem to working:

```
router.post('/graphs', (req, res) => {
const graph = new Graph();
graph.nodes = [{id: req.body.nodes.id}];
graph.links = [{source: req.body.source, target: req.body.target}];


graph.save((err) => {
if(err) return res.status(500).json({ message: 'internal error' })
res.json({ message: 'saved...' })
})
});
```

For example I want to achieve something like this as a final result:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id": "root"
            },
            {
                "id": "input"
            },
            {
                "id": "component"
            }
        ],
        "links": [
            {
                "source": "component",
                "target": "root"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I a testing the operation with Postman
I am in a kind of dead end regarding how to proceed so I hope you can hint me something!

Answer (score 1):

in your creation of the object , creat it like this

```
router.post('/graphs', (req, res) => {

const graph = new Graph({
 nodes:[{id:req.body.nodes.id}],
 links:[{source: req.body.source, target: req.body.target}]
}); // you need to include your data inside the instance of the model when you create it that was the problem.. It should work fine now
```

In your code you don't actually create the array that you have defined in your schema. So tally with your schema like above and then save. below

```
graph.save((err) => {
if(err) {

res.status(500).json({ message: 'internal error' });
throw err;
}else{
res.send({ message: 'saved...' });
}

})
});
```

this is the way you have currently posted the question.. so the answer is valid for that, but I assume this should be sufficient enough for you to figure out what was the problem ..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After that, what is the right way to test this via postman? Because when I tired it returned an html insted of the json.

Comment: I still get an html with this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;id&#39; of undefined`

Comment: try trowing the error like i have done .Changed the code again check it. and let me know whats the  console say when the app crashes. That happens because the app crashes